# How to use if2/3 in Gekko

Tags: gekko

The problem I am optimizing is the building of power plants in a transmission network. To do this I'm placing power plants at every bus and let the optimization tell me which ones should be build to minimize running cost.

To model the placing of the plant I tried using an array of binary variables that would flag i.e. be one if the plant is used at all and 0 otherwise. Then in the Objective function to minimize I multiply this array by a constant: `USEW`.

I have made several attempt without any working. The one that seemed to work was using the [if2](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=if2#logical-functions) `Gekko` function directly in the Obj. func. However I'm getting really odd results. My code is a bit long so I'll post just the relevant lines hopefully the idea would be clear, if not please let me know and I post the whole thing.

```py
bus=node=24
t=24
Sbase=100.
Gen = 12
VOLL = 10000.
VOLW = 50.
USEW = 100.
Pw = m.Array(m.Var,(bus,t), lb=0., ub=0., value=0.)
for b in range(bus):
    m.Minimize( np.sum(VOLL*lsh[b,:] + VOLW*Pc[b,:])*Sbase \
               + m.if2(-1.*Sbase*m.sum(Pw[b,:]),1,0)*USEW )
```

The problem is in the `if2` part. If I remove it I get expected results but then the decision of which plant to place is lost. I tried as well with `if3` but didn't work either. From what I see it seems like the optimizer is trying to minimize `Pw[b,:]` because the result contains only zeros. Somehow bypassing the `if2` part and getting into the inner `sum`.

Based on the documentation, this part: `m.if2(-1.*Sbase*m.sum(Pw[b,:]),1,0)` should return `0` or `1` but it doesn't seem like is doing that. I'm multiplying by `-1` because `Pw` is always positive and I want to detect when `Pw>0`.

I would like help on how to properly use the conditional function for this purpose.
Thanks

**EDIT1**
Consider the following case:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
Sbase=100.
Pw = array([[[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0],
    [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0],
    [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]],
   [[10.0], [10.0], [10.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0],
    [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0],
    [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]]], dtype=object)

# for np.sum(Pw[0,:])=0.0
print('sum of Pw[0,:]=', np.sum(Pw[0,:]))
print(m.if3(-1.*Sbase*np.sum(Pw[0,:]),1,0).value)
print(m.if3(-1.*Sbase*np.sum(Pw[0,:]),0,1).value)
# for np.sum(Pw[1,:])=30.0
print('sum of Pw[1,:]=', np.sum(Pw[1,:]))
print(m.if3(-1.*Sbase*np.sum(Pw[1,:]),1,0).value)
print(m.if3(-1.*Sbase*np.sum(Pw[1,:]),0,1).value)
```

The result is always the same: `0`. It doesn't matter if I swap `x1` and `x2` or if the condition >=0 or <0:

```
0.0
sum of Pw[0,:]= 0.0
0 #result 1
0 #result 2
sum of Pw[1,:]= 30.0
0 #result 3
0 #result 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that you can try is to use a switch point that is 1e-3 (or a certain minimum used) instead of zero. When the switch point is at zero and the condition is `1e-10` then the output will be `1` because it is greater than the switch point. This is needed because Gekko uses gradient based optimizers that have a solution tolerance of `1e-6` (default) so a solution within that tolerance is acceptable.

There are a [couple examples in the documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html) that may also help. You may also want to look at the `sign2`/`sign3` functions and the `max2`/`max3` functions that may also give you the desired result.

**`if2` Documentation**

IF conditional with complementarity constraint switch variable. The traditional method for IF statements is not continuously differentiable and can cause a gradient-based optimizer to fail to converge. The `if2` method uses a binary switching variable to determine whether `y=x1` (when `condition<0`) or `y=x2` (when `condition>=0`):

**`if3` Documentation**

IF conditional with a binary switch variable. The traditional method for IF statements is not continuously differentiable and can cause a gradient-based optimizer to fail to converge. The `if3` method uses a binary switching variable to determine whether `y=x1` (when `condition<0`) or `y=x2` (when `condition>=0`).

**Usage**

`y = m.if3(condition,x1,x2)`

*Inputs:*

- `condition`: GEKKO variable, parameter, or expression
- `x1` and `x2`: GEKKO variable, parameter, or expression

*Output:*

- `y = x1` when `condition<0`
- `y = x2` when `condition>=0`

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
p = m.Param()
y = m.if3(p-4,p**2,p+1)

# solve with condition<0
p.value = 3
m.solve(disp=False)
print(y.value)

# solve with condition>=0
p.value = 5
m.solve(disp=False)
print(y.value)
```

There is [additional information](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/LogicalConditions) on logical conditions with gradient-based optimizers and the difference between `2 (MPCC)` and `3 (binary)` types.

**Response to EDIT1**

Because Gekko always uses a switch condition of `0`, we can modify the switch condition with `condition<swc` and fit it back into the gekko form with `condition-swc<0`. From the example in my response, we can move the switch condition by `swc=0.1`.

```py
swc = 0.1
y = m.if3(p-4-swc,p**2,p+1)
```

In your case, you could use `swc=1e-3` or something a little higher to avoid solutions right at the switch condition. While `if3` typically takes longer to solve, I generally get better results than `if2`, especially if there are competing objectives that interfere with the `if2` MPCC.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The first paragraph of your answer contains several concepts that I can't put apart. How can I set the switch point to 1e-3? as I see it the switch point is hard-coded for both if2/3 to 0: condition<0 and condition>=0. Then you say "When the switch point is at zero..." but in the previous sentence it was set to 1e-3. I know my confusion is silly but please bear with me.